# Backbone js: Type error when running jasmine-karma unit test

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, karma-jasmine

This is the error I'm getting when I'm running jasmine-karma unit test in backbone.js using lightbox.

`TyperError: undefined bn is not an object (evaluating 'this.$lightbox.find') in node_modules/@t-and-l/ds/js/scripts/module/Overlay.js`

Please help me out.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask The error message is a bit vague. Do you have additional information? Thanks.

Comment: @GBouffard you can type `[ask]` to get that link in future ;) (it's one of the magic links)

Comment: I think you'll have better luck reporting this in the Github issues of respective library, in this case could be lightbox that has dependency on `Overlay.js`

Comment: @TJ Thanks for the tip. Awesome magic stuff :)